# How to apply index in descending order in grails domain class?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have written a domain class

```
class ReportCallByUser {
Integer userId;
String userName;
String reportName;
Date timeOfReportCall;

static constraints = {
}

static mapping = {

    timeOfReportCall index: 'time_of_report_call_index'
}
```

The last line creates an index in database but in ascending order. How can I create index on '*timeOfReportCall*' with descending order?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as `order` in regards to index creation. It's the query's ability to specify the ordering:

```
ReportCallByUser.list( [ sort:'timeOfReportCall', order:'[desc|asc]' ] )
```

Comment: at least postgres allows to have "ASC, DESC, NULLS FIRST, and/or NULLS LAST" for an index.  see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html

Comment: it might well be, but you can't make it inside GORM's `static mapping` builder. smth like `timeOfReportCall index: 'time_of_report_call_index', order:'desc'`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want the results in descending order by default when you query the database using GORM. If that is the case, you can specify sort order in your mapping as such.

```
static mapping = {
    sort timeOfReportCall:"desc"
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I want to apply index so that I can get result by descending order on timeOfReportCall quickly. In the code snipped in 'static mapping' closure creates index in ASCENDING order. So I am seeking the way to apply index with descending order by coding.